# ReferenceError: $$ is not defined jQuery error?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a simple example of a group of divs that can be sorted either by their HTML content or by custom attribute values:

Sort alphabetically by HTML content

Sort low to high by the value of the attribute "sortweight"HTML:

I have tried following code and got error

> ReferenceError: $$ is not defined

HTML

```
<div id="sortexample">
    <div class="sortitem" sortweight="5">Pears [sortweight: 5]</div>
    <div class="sortitem" sortweight="3">Apples [sortweight: 3]</div>
    <div class="sortitem" sortweight="1">Cherries [sortweight: 1]</div>
    <div class="sortitem" sortweight="4">Oranges [sortweight: 4]</div>
    <div class="sortitem" sortweight="2">Strawberries [sortweight: 2]</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// sort all divs with classname 'sortitem' by html content
function sort_div_content() {
    // copy all divs into array and destroy them in the page
    divsbucket = new Array();
    divslist = $$('div.sortitem');
    for (a=0;a<divslist.length;a++) {
        divsbucket[a] = divslist[a].dispose();
    }

    // sort array by HTML content of divs
    divsbucket.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() === b.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    });

    // re-inject sorted divs into page
    for (a=0;a<divslist.length;a++) {
        divsbucket[a].inject($('sortexample'));
    }
}

// sort by attributes - usage for our example: sort_div_attribute('sortweight');
function sort_div_attribute(attname) {
    // copy all divs into array and destroy them in the page
    divsbucket = new Array();
    divslist = $$('div.sortitem');
    for (a=0;a<divslist.length;a++) {
        divsbucket[a] = new Array();
        // we'vev passed in the name of the attribute to sort by
        divsbucket[a][0] = divslist[a].get(attname);
        divsbucket[a][1] = divslist[a].dispose();
    }

    // sort array by sort attribute content
    divsbucket.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a[0].toLowerCase() === b[0].toLowerCase()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (a[0].toLowerCase() > b[0].toLowerCase()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    });

    // re-inject sorted divs into page
    for (a=0;a<divslist.length;a++) {
        divsbucket[a][1].inject($('sortexample'));
    }
}
```

I dont know why i got this error

Comment: There is no such `div` attribute named "sortweight" try "data-sortweight"), and did you intend to use the jQuery `$()` function (not the `$$()` function)?

Comment: An aside: You should be declaring the scope of your variables using `var`, `let`, or `const` as in, for example, `for(let a=0;` or `const divbucket = new Array();`.

Comment: @terrymorse Ye,but i got another error 'Uncaught TypeError: divslist[a].dispose is not a function at sort_div_content'

Comment: I don't think there is a jQuery method called `.dispose()`. If you want to remove an element from the DOM, try using [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/#remove-selector).

Answer (score 0):

On the fifth line, it says `divslist = $$('div.sortitem');`, but $$ is not defined. You have to use $ instead of $$.

`divslist = $('div.sortitem');` This would be better

Comment: Ye,but i got another error 'Uncaught TypeError: divslist[a].dispose is not a function
    at sort_div_content'

Comment: If you are trying to remove elements from the DOM, you should use divslist[a].remove instead of divslist[a].remove